# Background image not changing onclick until mouse move in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, background-image

I'm trying to dynamically change the background of a site when a user clicks on a link on my page, using pure Javascript.

The JS cycles through 4 images on clicking the anchor on the HTML page. In Chrome/Safari, it works a treat. However, in Firefox (build 23.0.1) the background goes blank until the user moves their cursor. So, the onclick fires, but the next background image doesn't show-up until the mouse moves AFTER the click. Does anyone know what causes this? I'd like to avoid using jQuery, if possible or at least to understand what jQuery is doing to avoid this type of issue ...

The HTML:

```
<a onclick="nextBackground()" id="startSwapping">Next Background</a>
```

The Javascript:

```
var count = 0;
var backgrounds = new Array();
var background = "";

backgrounds[0] = "alaska.jpg";
backgrounds[1] = "delaware.jpg";
backgrounds[2] = "idaho.jpg";
backgrounds[3] = "massachusetts.jpg";   

function nextBackground() {
    if(count >= 4) {
        count = 0;
    }
    background = "url('images/"+backgrounds[count]+"')";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = background;
    count++;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have link to this page on web?

Comment: Reproduced in FF 23.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/YD7db/

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddles. Yes, that is exactly the issue I'm having. Maybe I just have to pre-load the images, then? Any thoughts on the best way to pre-load with pure Javascript?

Comment: Strange, seems to work after images are cached or if Firebug is monitoring network downloads.

Comment: Now I cannot reproduce anymore (even after clearing the cache). I think it's just a latency problem, the image will only display after it has fully loaded. Yes, try preloading them.

Comment: I use the pre-loading technique I found here: http://perishablepress.com/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/

And it is now working fine. If you have a better suggestion for pre-loading, though, I would be interested to hear. Thank you, everyone for the help.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use jQuery in your code, remove the onclick from the html, and handle that events in your js.
jQuery will take care for you of the crossbrowsing issues. It's really easy to move your code from plain js to jQuery. Ask for help if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, pre-loading is your solution. Luckily I've had to do some preloading before, and I have a script handy. I've implemented it into the same structure as the fiddle above by bfavaretto

http://jsfiddle.net/wQq5M/

Create a `LoadingGroup` like this:

```
var lg = new LoadingGroup(backgrounds, function(imgs){
console.log("all done...", imgs);
nextBackground();
});
```

When all the images are done, the callback fires and the first image shows up. Hope this helps.

Cheers.